# Insert Parent and Child Objects of One Type within One DML statement

Tags: apex, dml, externalid, childrecords

I want to insert Parent and Child Accounts in one DML statement.
I know it can be done for related Contact/Account objects [using External Id field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm), but it doesn't work in my case.

Running the following code

```
Account childAccount = new Account(Name='Child Account');
Account parentAccountRef = new Account(External_Id__c='123');
childAccount.Parent = parentAccountRef;
Account parentAccount = new Account(Name='Parent Account', External_Id__c='123');

Database.insert(new Account[] {parentAccount, childAccount});
```

I get the error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first
>   error: INVALID_FIELD, Foreign key external ID: 123 not found for field
>   External_Id__c in entity Account: []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach only works with different types. Take a look at [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) (emphasis mine):

> You can use external ID fields as foreign keys to create parent and child records **of different sObject types** in a single step instead of creating the parent record first, querying its ID, and then creating the child record.
>
> ...
>
> You can create related records that are up to 10 levels deep. **Also, the related records created in a single call must have different sObject types.** For more information, see [Creating Records for Different Object Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#MixedSaveSection) in the SOAP API Developer's Guide.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I missed this statement in documentation.